# Why does my uploaded image not display on my Laravel website?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm building a website using Laravel. I implemented a service where users can upload an image. For this, I used [laravel-medialibrary](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v8/introduction/). I wrote some code to have the website display the image the user uploads. Though, instead of an image, the only thing that displays is an icon (see attached image). When I right-click and open the image address in another tab I get a 404 not found error.

It's the same issue as this one: https://github.com/vanilophp/demo/issues/17

I already did `php artisan storage:link` but it already exists. 
I also changed my APP_URL to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
None of these fixes worked for me.

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1c2G.png)

Comment: What is broken image's link? And write also APP_URL in .env

Comment: This is the image URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/3/responsive-images/IMG_20200502_181155___media_library_original_4032_3024.jpg